# Why Custom Validator doesnt work in the document.ready of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, asp.net

I call a function trought my Custom validator on .NET :

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chbNota" runat="server" />
<asp:CustomValidator ClientValidationFunction="RequiredPrivacy" Runat="server" ID="cvPrivacy" onservervalidate="CustomValidatorchkPrivacy_ServerValidate" >&nbsp;*</asp:CustomValidator>
```

Now, If I declare the function into $(document).ready(function() as :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function RequiredPrivacy(oSrc, args) {
        if (!$('#<%=chbNota.ClientID%>').prop("checked")) args.IsValid = false;
    }
});
```

the whole Validator on client side go to true.

Why this behaviour? If I move that function out of $(document).ready(function() all work perfectly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the function inside your "ready" handler, it's hidden from the global scope. It's like a local variable just for the handler function, in other words.

There's no need to define functions intended to be globally visible inside a "ready" handler. If you *really* want to, however, you could do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window['RequiredPrivacy'] = function(oSrc, args) {
        if (!$('#<%=chbNota.ClientID%>').prop("checked")) args.IsValid = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Uhm...not sure to understand what do you mean.. :)

Comment: Look at the code.  The "ready" handler is a **function**, right?  Well, when you define another function *inside* a function, it's local to that outer function.  It cannot be seen by other code. It's like a local variable in a C# method.

Comment: Well that I don't know; I don't know much about the ASP validation mechanism. Because an attempt to call that function would result in a JavaScript error, maybe that's what the library does to handle it. Just guessing.

Answer (score 1):

The function must be declared in the global namespace.  When you place the function within $(document).ready, it scopes the function and prevents the built in CustomValidator javascript hooks from finding that function.